# Java class not found errors while running

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have a class that is having some dependency problems referencing external library files. Every time I try to run this on the server I get errors saying class not found, such as this:

> SEVERE: Class [ org/json/JSONException ] not found. Error while loading [ class com.myproj.logic.Driver ]

this is preventing the class from executing. I tried taking out the specific throws execption by just saying "throws exception" and got the following error:

> WARNING: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Driver method public void com..logic.Driver.initURL() throws java.lang.Exception
> javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Driver

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

```
@Singleton
public class Driver {
 
@EJB RSSbean rssbean;    
   
@PostConstruct
@Schedule(hour ="*/1", minute ="*/1", second ="*/1", persistent = false)
public void initURL() throws IOException, JSONException{
     
    URL twitterSource = new URL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=news");
    ByteArrayOutputStream urlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                IOUtils.copy(twitterSource.openStream(), urlOutputStream);
                String urlContents = urlOutputStream.toString();
                JSONObject thisobject = new JSONObject(urlContents);
                JSONArray names = thisobject.names();
                JSONArray asArray = thisobject.toJSONArray(names);
                JSONArray resultsArray = thisobject.getJSONArray("results");
                                
           JSONObject jsonObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    
            String twitterText = jsonObject.getString("text");
                    
            //System.out.println(twitterText);
            System.out.println("Calling rssbean from Driver");
            rssbean.updateDatabase("twitterText");
                    
}
}
```

I have edited the Java classpath and added a user library for each of these as well as editing the Build Path of the project. The libraries are displayed in the list and I don't get compiler errors so at least Eclipse has recognized them. The problem comes during execution so I think something is wrong there.

Should I edit the classpath in Windows>Preferences>Java>Classpath> and add the Jars there? I have not had to do this for any other libraries before.

Comment: Compilation and execution classpathes are different. How do you launch the application ? Is the missing librairy listed in yout runtime classpath ?

Comment: I'm running it in glassfish 3.1.  I think my build paths are fine it must be the classpath. How can I check this to make sure they're there?  If I go to windows > preferences > Java > build path > class path> there are only JRE library files there.

Comment: I think you should add the jar that contains the missing com.myproj.logic.Driver class to your webapp's WEB-INF/lib directory, so that it can be used (and found) at runtime. Or, if it isn't a jar but a single class, add it to the WEB-INF/classes directory. In either cases, redeploy your application and test with the new jar or class added.

Comment: com.myproj.logic.Driver is the calling class and it is in an EJB project. The missing class is the org/json/json.jsonexception.  Which is just added to the build path of the project. But I will try adding that missing json class to the web-inf/classes directory. Isn't this an odd way to add library dependencies?

Comment: Well, no. All the *runtime* dependencies of a Java webapp, regardless of which server it's deployed on, must be either put in jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory, or as simple classes in the WEB-INF/classes directory. And this runtime classpath has nothing to do with the build path you set in your IDE.

Comment: Ah, which I guess would make sense because for webapps they have to be able to be packaged up and deployed whihc means actually adding the libraries to the webproject and not just referencing them in local directories. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I assume the org.json.JSONException class comes from some opensource Java/json library (like Jackson - http://jackson.codehaus.org/). If this is the case, I'd recommend to put the complete librairy jar in the runtime classpath, rather than only the missong org.json.JSONException class.

Comment: Would you mind up-voting some of my comments if it helped you ? I posted only comments, and not a "real" answer that could get "accepted"...

Comment: Thank you. Hummm I'm no EJB expert, so I don't know. Maybe the META-INF is equivalent to the webapp's WEB-INF directory ? That would make sense, somehow.

Comment: Well I added those jars to the build paths of both directories and it still cannot find that class... I'm going to try rebuilding the jar. and See if that helps. It's just weird that Eclipse recognizes it during compile time but the server gives an error during runtime...maybe the glassfish runtime environment can be modified to be able to see these files.

Comment: Again, let me stress that *a webapp must bring all its dependencies with it*. Compiling it in Eclipse, Ant, or whatever has absolutely nothing to do with it. Even if you launch the server from inside Eclipse. The only way is to add the required libs either in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes (maybe META-INF/lib works too, I don't know)

Comment: I have added them to the WEB-INF/lib folder and it is still having problems. : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you have to add any library files in the Glassfish/domain/lib directory before they're recognized by glassfish on the server.

Comment: Hate to answer my own question but this was not pulling up for me based on the keywords I was using.

Comment: Or, as in my case /WEB-INF/lib/ needs jettison.jar